# Conectar a un WCF desde una Biblioteca de Clases

Tags: c#, wcf, vb6

Estimados es posible invocar un servicio (WCF) en una biblioteca de clases?. Estoy creando una dll para poder usarla en un proyecto en VB 6.0 y necesito consumir un Servicio. Cuando ejecuto el programa me da el siguiente error :

> No se encontró el elemento de extremo predeterminado que hace
>   referencia al contrato 'wcfGestion.IGestion_v2' en la sección de
>   configuración de cliente de ServiceModel. La razón puede ser que no se
>   encontró ningún archivo de configuración para la aplicación o que no
>   se encontró

En el proyecto de Biblioteca de Clases tengo generado el archivo app.config:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IGestion_v2" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:50638/svcGestion_v2.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IGestion_v2"
                contract="wcfGestion.IGestion_v2" name="BasicHttpBinding_IGestion_v2" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

y el Código como lo Instancio es:

```
    public string ConsumirWCF()
    {
        wcfGestion.Gestion_v2Client objServicio = new wcfGestion.Gestion_v2Client();
        return DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
    }
```

Comment: el problema que veo es que la configuracion se toma desde el proyecto que ejecuta, si defines un app.config en el proyecto class library no lo reconoce, sino que lo hara desde el proyecto ejecutable y entiendo en tu caso es vb6 lo cual es un problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias intentar creando un archivo con el nombre `MyVB6Program.exe.config` y poner alli la configuracion que requiere `wcf`

Entiendo que al definir el nombre de la configuracion de esa forma lo reconocer la dll net

[Utilising a .NET DLL with a .config file in VB6](http://versioncommand.com/?p=46)

Del enlace, la traducción del contenido es:

Esto no es una buena práctica, pero a veces es necesario usar un archivo de configuración para una DLL desarrollada en.NET que luego necesita ser llamada desde VB6.

Para depurar una aplicación/exe VB6 que utilice un dll.NET con un archivo.config debe crear un archivo vb6.exe.config en la misma carpeta que el ejecutable VB6. Normalmente es C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98.

Cuando se compila el archivo dll/exe de VB6, el archivo de configuración debe tener el mismo nombre que el archivo dll/exe con extensión.config y estar ubicado en la misma ubicación que el archivo dll/exe.

y el código de ejemplo es:

```
'Fetch the connection string from the app.config file
Dim settings As ConnectionStringSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(name)
If settings IsNot Nothing Then
' Retrieve the partial connection string.
Dim connectString As String = settings.ConnectionString
' Create a new SqlConnectionStringBuilder based on the partial connection string retrieved from the config file.
Dim builder As DbConnectionStringBuilder
'We need to act differently depending on wether we are using Access or SQL
If settings.ProviderName.ToUpper = "SYSTEM.DATA.ODBC" Then
builder = New OdbcConnectionStringBuilder(connectString)
' Supply the additional values.
builder.Add("Uid", "USER_NAME_HERE")
builder.Add("Pwd", "PASSWORD_HERE")
'This is a bit of a hack but we can check the odbc connection string to see if it contains the phrase 'SQL Server'
'as all sql server odbc connection strings up to and including version 11 will contain this phrase
If settings.ConnectionString.IndexOf("SQL Server", 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &lt;&gt; -1 Then
useSQLServer = True 'Set the useSQLServer flag
Else
Throw New Exception("Provider '" &amp; settings.ProviderName &amp; "' is not allowed.")
End If
Return builder.ConnectionString
Else
Throw New Exception("Unable to retrieve app.config connectionstrings.")
End If
```

Comment: Excelente. Probado y Funcionando. Muchas Gracias

Comment: Leandro, tus respuestas son buenas, solo un detalle, a veces dependen mucho del enlace, por ello, me tomé el atrevimiento de extraer el contenido de dicho enlace y publicarlo en tu pregunta, espero que todo vaya bien. Saludos :D

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer que en la libreria de clases, en los mtodos que sabes que van a usar al Servicio Wcf reciban como parámetro la dirección del servicio, para que los puedas parametrizar en el origen, osea en la aplicacion VB6
Ya en la libreria de clases instancias el Endpoint Address:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(endpointAddressFromVb6);
IServicioWcfParaConsumir svc = new ServicioWcfParaConsumirClient(binding, address);
```